# python: checking then updating the value in a text file

Tags: python, replace

I am really new at python and looking for a little help. I have a text file with the current data:

```
Tue Jun 25 **15** 336 0 0 0 0 0
Tue Jun 25 **04** 12682 0 0 0 0 0 
Tue Jun 25 **05** 12636 0 0 0 0 0
Tue Jun 25 **06** 12450 0 0 0 0 0 
Tue Jun 25 **07** 12640 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to go through each line and check to see if the  is greater then 12. If it is greater then 12 i want to subtract 12 from it then write back to the with the new number.

below is the code that i have so far:

```
infile = open("filelocation", "a+") #open the file with the data above and append /             open it

def fun (line, infile): # define a function to to go to position 12 - 14 (which is      where the date in bod is) and set it to an integer 
    t = infile[12:14]
    p = int(t)

    if p > 12: # here is the logic to see if it is greater then 12 to subtract 12 and attempt to write back to the file.
        p = p - 12

        k = str(p)
        infile.write(k)
    else:
        print p # probably not needed but i had it here for testing
    return

# I was having an issue with going to the next line and found this code.
for line in infile:
    print line, infile
    line = fun(line, infile.next())
    break
infile.close()
```

The main issue is it is not iterating through each line or making the update. There even might be a better way to do what i am trying to do just don't have the knowledge yet or understand the capability of some of the functions. Any help with this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = open("filelocation").readlines()
with open("filelocation", "w") as out:
    for line in inp:
        t = line[12:14]
        p = int(t)
        if p>12:
            line = '{}{:02}{}'.format(line[:12], p-12, line[14:])
        out.write(line)
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i try to run your code:

     line[12:14] = '{:02}'.format(p-12)
     TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I feel like we are close... when i run this code it still outputs:

     `Tue Jun 25 **15** 336 0 0 0 0 0
     Tue Jun 25 **04** 12682 0 0 0 0 0 
     Tue Jun 25 **05** 12636 0 0 0 0 0
     Tue Jun 25 **06** 12450 0 0 0 0 0 
     Tue Jun 25 **07** 12640 0 0 0 0 0 `

and i did a print on the variable t and it has the correct value just looks like it isn't writing that value to the document. almost like "line" isn't getting updated with the value "t".

Comment: looks like i made a mistake when copying your code. looks like it is working except that is going over the first line like 10 times. Here is the code that I have:

`inp = open("file").readlines()`
`with open("otherfile", "w+") as out:`
    `for line in inp:`
       `t = line[12:14]`
       `p = int(t)`
       `if p > 12:`
            `final = '{}{:02}{}'.format(line[:12], p - 12, line[14:])`
        `out.write(final)`

and here is the output for the first 10 lines then it starts to replace the value with  -12 value:
`Tue Jun 25 03 336 0 0 0 0 0`
`Tue Jun 25 03 336 0 0 0 0 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in infile:
    print line, infile
    line = fun(line, infile.next())
    break
```

`break` leaves the current loop, so this will only run on the first line, then stop.

Why is your `fun` function operating on the file and not the line? You already have the line, so there's no reason to read it again, and I'd argue that writing it back like this is a bad idea. Try to make it work with this function signature:

```
def fun(line):
    # do things
    return changed_line
```

For handling the file, you can use [`with` statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to make this simpler and more fool-proof:

```
with open("filelocation", "a+") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = fun(line)
# infile is closed here
```

For output, it's fairly difficult to write back to the same file you're reading from, so I'd recommend just opening a new output file:

```
with open(input_filename, "r") as input_file:
    with open(output_filename, "w") as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            output_file.write(fun(line))
```

Or you could read the whole thing in then write it all back out (but depending on the size of the file, this could use a lot of memory):

```
output = ""
with open(filename, "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        output += fun(line)
with open(filename, "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write(output)
```